# How to extract a segmented object after it has been masked using Maskrcnn

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have an image. I am using Matterports Maskrcnn algorithm to perform segmentation. Now I have the segmented masks aftr detection. I want to extract this object and then create a new blank image (black background) of the same initial image size and just put this masked object in the same exact position as in the original image. Essentially, I want to extract the object and remove the entire background so that I can easily identify the object. How do I do this using python?

[image: Output image]

This is my existing code

```
import os
import sys
import random
import math
import numpy as np
import skimage.io
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mrcnn

# Root directory of the project
ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath("")
print(ROOT_DIR)
# Import Mask RCNN
sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)  # To find local version of the library
from mrcnn import utils
import mrcnn.model as modellib
from mrcnn import visualize
# Import COCO config
sys.path.append(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "samples/coco/"))  # To find local version
import coco

# Directory to save logs and trained model
MODEL_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "logs")

# Local path to trained weights file
COCO_MODEL_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
# Download COCO trained weights from Releases if needed
if not os.path.exists(COCO_MODEL_PATH):
    utils.download_trained_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH)

# Directory of images to run detection on
IMAGE_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "images")

class InferenceConfig(coco.CocoConfig):
    # Set batch size to 1 since we'll be running inference on
    # one image at a time. Batch size = GPU_COUNT * IMAGES_PER_GPU
    GPU_COUNT = 1
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1

config = InferenceConfig()
#config.display()

# Create model object in inference mode.
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=MODEL_DIR, config=config)

# Load weights trained on MS-COCO
model.load_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH, by_name=True)

# COCO Class names
# Index of the class in the list is its ID. For example, to get ID of
# the teddy bear class, use: class_names.index('teddy bear')
class_names = ['BG', 'person', 'bicycle', 'car', 'motorcycle', 'airplane',
               'bus', 'train', 'truck', 'boat', 'traffic light',
               'fire hydrant', 'stop sign', 'parking meter', 'bench', 'bird',
               'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'sheep', 'cow', 'elephant', 'bear',
               'zebra', 'giraffe', 'backpack', 'umbrella', 'handbag', 'tie',
               'suitcase', 'frisbee', 'skis', 'snowboard', 'sports ball',
               'kite', 'baseball bat', 'baseball glove', 'skateboard',
               'surfboard', 'tennis racket', 'bottle', 'wine glass', 'cup',
               'fork', 'knife', 'spoon', 'bowl', 'banana', 'apple',
               'sandwich', 'orange', 'broccoli', 'carrot', 'hot dog', 'pizza',
               'donut', 'cake', 'chair', 'couch', 'potted plant', 'bed',
               'dining table', 'toilet', 'tv', 'laptop', 'mouse', 'remote',
               'keyboard', 'cell phone', 'microwave', 'oven', 'toaster',
               'sink', 'refrigerator', 'book', 'clock', 'vase', 'scissors',
               'teddy bear', 'hair drier', 'toothbrush']

import cv2
# Load a random image from the images folder
image = skimage.io.imread("sample_images/sample9.jpg")

# Run detection
results = model.detect([image], verbose=1)
print(results)
# Visualize results
r = results[0]
visualize.display_instances(image, r['rois'], r['masks'], r['class_ids'], 
                            class_names, r['scores'])
cv2.imwrite("hi.jpg",image)
```

**EDIT**
this is the code for visualize.display_instances()

```
def display_instances(image, boxes, masks, class_ids, class_names,
                      scores=None, title="",
                      figsize=(16, 16), ax=None,
                      show_mask=True, show_bbox=True,
                      colors=None, captions=None):
    """
    boxes: [num_instance, (y1, x1, y2, x2, class_id)] in image coordinates.
    masks: [height, width, num_instances]
    class_ids: [num_instances]
    class_names: list of class names of the dataset
    scores: (optional) confidence scores for each box
    title: (optional) Figure title
    show_mask, show_bbox: To show masks and bounding boxes or not
    figsize: (optional) the size of the image
    colors: (optional) An array or colors to use with each object
    captions: (optional) A list of strings to use as captions for each object
    """
    # Number of instances
    N = boxes.shape[0]
    if not N:
        print("\n*** No instances to display *** \n")
    else:
        assert boxes.shape[0] == masks.shape[-1] == class_ids.shape[0]

    # If no axis is passed, create one and automatically call show()
    auto_show = False
    if not ax:
        _, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=figsize)
        auto_show = True

    # Generate random colors
    colors = colors or random_colors(N)

    # Show area outside image boundaries.
    height, width = image.shape[:2]
    ax.set_ylim(height + 10, -10)
    ax.set_xlim(-10, width + 10)
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.set_title(title)

    masked_image = image.astype(np.uint32).copy()
    for i in range(N):
        color = colors[i]

        # Bounding box
        if not np.any(boxes[i]):
            # Skip this instance. Has no bbox. Likely lost in image cropping.
            continue
        y1, x1, y2, x2 = boxes[i]
        if show_bbox:
            p = patches.Rectangle((x1, y1), x2 - x1, y2 - y1, linewidth=2,
                                alpha=0.7, linestyle="dashed",
                                edgecolor=color, facecolor='none')
            ax.add_patch(p)

        # Label
        if not captions:
            class_id = class_ids[i]
            score = scores[i] if scores is not None else None
            label = class_names[class_id]
            caption = "{} {:.3f}".format(label, score) if score else label
        else:
            caption = captions[i]
        ax.text(x1, y1 + 8, caption,
                color='w', size=11, backgroundcolor="none")

        # Mask
        mask = masks[:, :, i]
        if show_mask:
            masked_image = apply_mask(masked_image, mask, color)

        # Mask Polygon
        # Pad to ensure proper polygons for masks that touch image edges.
        padded_mask = np.zeros(
            (mask.shape[0] + 2, mask.shape[1] + 2), dtype=np.uint8)
        padded_mask[1:-1, 1:-1] = mask
        contours = find_contours(padded_mask, 0.5)
        for verts in contours:
            # Subtract the padding and flip (y, x) to (x, y)
            verts = np.fliplr(verts) - 1
            p = Polygon(verts, facecolor="none", edgecolor=color)
            ax.add_patch(p)
    ax.imshow(masked_image.astype(np.uint8))
    #cv2.imshow("Hi",masked_image.astype(np.uint8))
    #cv2.waitKey(0)
    if auto_show:
        plt.show()
```

Comment: can you add what does your `result` look like? (shape and content)

Comment: @DominikFicek Ive attached the out put image. I want only the apple to be extracted and create another blank image with just the apple in its corresponding position

Comment: Can you link the docs of the output of MaskRCNN? What did you try and didn't work?

Comment: okay, can you also show `visualize.display_instances()` ?

Comment: @Gulzar https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/README.md
This is the link to the docs. This was run in jupyter notebook. However I want to run this directly in my ec2 instance frm the terminal. So i will not be using matplotlib or anything. I want o tcreate individual images for each apple in the frame.

Comment: @DominikFicek I ve added the code

Comment: And what have you tried and failed?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `results[0]['masks']` is the information you need and you can just mask the original image like this

```py
# Rows x Columns x Classes
masks = results[0]['masks']
# if pixel is 1 for any class
mask = np.any(masks.astype(np.bool), axis=-1)
# apply mask
masked_img = image * mask
```

Comment: Where do i add this? I want to extract the pixels which are part of one instance (apple) and then put that apple in the black image.

Comment: do you want just apples or all classes? you can use this after you read your image and make predictions at `results = model.detect([image], verbose=1)`